# Oozie multiple ok

Tags: oozie-workflow

I have a use-case where one node has to be called after every transition irrespective the action is getting failed or succeed. Oozie does not allow multiple "ok to" for the same node. Is there any way to achieve the same.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to branch to the *same* action whether the status is OK or not. Then you can branch to a `decision` to check the actual status of the original action, then either continue or fail.

Comment: Thanks Samson. But I am handling it through Java API.

Comment: Never heard of that API. Does that mean you only have access to a crippled version of the regular Oozie workflow? If yes, please make it explicit in your question...